# Inter-feature ratio explicitly or implicitly?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection

Let's say I have two numerical features were is suspect that the ratio between them is the most meaningful way of looking at them. I have a NN learner.
Should I add the ratio as a third feature or is this just idiotic?

In other words: Would it make sense to do a feature selection with all three of them and see if one or two of them suffice? Or is this just a waste of time because it doesn't matter what feature of the three of them I remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases (depending on exactly what NN you are using etc) the solution will be a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of the features. In that case the ratio between them will not be implicitly encoded. e.g. if you have features $x_1$ and $x_2$, and a third feature $x_3 = \frac{x_1}{x_2}$. Then if your solution was in a vector $\bf{w}$ with $w_1 = 1$, $w_2 = 2$, and $w_3 = 3$, the final solution for an example $\bf{x}_i$ is:

$y_i = \sum_j w_j x_j$

$ = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + w_3 x_3$

$ = x_1 + 2 x_2 + 3\frac{x_1}{x_2}$.

And yes you can feature select over all the features (the new feature is no different in that respect to the others).

If you are using some nonlinear mapping, however, it is possible that the ratio could be encoded, but there would probably be no harm in having the extra feature in there anyway.